# How can I verify that a program has been called by another program

Tags: anchor, program

I have a program which should be allowed to be called by whitelisted programs only.
Currently I solved the issue as such, but I wonder whether there are other more elegant solutions (maybe, by using `Instructions` sysvar, just like Metaplex does).

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(caller_id: Pubkey, caller_bump: u8)]
pub struct Whitelisted<'info> {
    #[account(
        seeds = [crate::SIGNATURE],
        bump = caller_bump,
        seeds::program = caller_id,
    )]
    pub caller_signature: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        constraint = state.can_be_called_by(caller_id),
    )]
    pub state: Account<'info, State>,
}

---snip---

pub fn whitelisted(
    ctx: Context<Whitelisted>, 
    _caller_id: Pubkey,
    _called_bump: u8,
) -> anchor_lang::Result<()> {
    ---snip---
}
```

And I have a caller sign `caller_signature` pda account with `invoke_signed` and also pass its address with a bump, which were stored beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, this is how Metaplex candy-machine-v2 does it:

```
use solana_program::sysvar::instructions::get_instruction_relative;

const ALLOWED_PROGRAM_ID: Pubkey = solana_program::pubkey!("...");

// in your instruction:

let current_ix = get_instruction_relative(
  0, 
  &ctx.accounts.instruction_sysvar_account.to_account_info()
).unwrap();

if !cmp_pubkeys(&current_ix.program_id, &ALLOWED_PROGRAM_ID) {
  // not my program - throw error!
}
```

You can get the instruction, which this CPI call is an inner instruction of, and check that it matches the program ID you expect.

[This](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/14812a07f5c51654d2c6d7937d716d6a34341355/candy-machine/program/src/processor/mint.rs#L120-L133) is the relevant part in candy-machine-v2 source code.

Comment: Note that if you have Program A => CPI into Program B => CPI into Program C.
Program C will see caller as Program A and not Program B